# Vuetify v-select input element does not hold any value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using a typical Vuetify's v-select component like this:

```
<v-select 
    :name="search['type']" 
    v-model="type" 
    :items="typeOptions" 
    label="Type"
>
</v-select>
```

where typeOptions is an array like this:

```
typeOptions: [
  { text: 'Residential', value: 'residential' },
  { text: 'Commercial', value: 'commercial' },
  { text: 'Land', value: 'land' },
  { text: 'Other', value: 'other' },
]
```

The problem is that while `v-model` holds the appropriate value, the input element with name `search['type']` that is created does not hold any value, so I cannot include this v-select component in a form that I want to submit.

Check my codepen [here](https://codepen.io/iiirxs/pen/OadWOg).

I could use a workaround here, by inserting a hidden input depending on this `v-model` but I don't find it the cleanest solution and in any case I think this should work properly and I cannot understand why it doesn't.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does that https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LXqaXV?editors=1010 solved your issue?

Comment: is that different from my codepen?

Comment: Yes look at the display of "search[]"

Comment: Οk, no, this is not what I want, the problem is the value of the input not the name of the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that currently Vuetify currently doesn't support regular form inputs for select, checkboxes and radio inputs. That means when someone is trying to submit them to a server, nothing will be submitted.

This feature is planned to be added on Vuetify 1.1 with the refactoring of input controls. More information on the issue [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/838).